# C - Cycle through all possible lowercase strings

Tags: c, string, recursion, cs50, brute-force

I'm learning C with the CS50 course problem set 2, using the crypt function to brute force guess a password. Currently writing a function that prints all possible strings of a certain length, eg:

```
aa
ab
...
az
ba
...
zy
zz
```

I've written a fairly simple recursive function to do so:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <string.h>

void stringcycler(int n, int passLength, char *pass)
// Scrolls through all lowercase letter combinations for a string of length passLength
// Expects an integer value of the length of the strng as both n and passLength
// Also expects a char* array of length passLength with all chars set to 'a' (and a null character)
{
    if(n != 0)
    {
        for(pass[passLength - n] = 'a'; pass[passLength - n] < 'z'; pass[passLength - n]++)
        {            
            stringcycler(n-1, passLength, pass);
            printf("%s\n", pass);
            // return 0;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{    
    // Initialise char *c, and scroll through letters
    int passLength = 2; // The number of characters you want to brute force guess
    char pass[passLength + 1]; //  Add 1 for the null character
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < passLength; i++) pass[i] = 'a'; // Set every char in pass to 'a'
    pass[passLength] = '\0'; // Set null character at the end of string

    stringcycler(passLength, passLength, pass);

    return 0;
}
```

It works for the most part, but only goes to yz. Whenever it sees a z it basically skips, so it goes to yz, then never does za to zz. If I add an = to the for loop line:

```
pass[passLength - n] < 'z';
```

ie.

```
pass[passLength - n] <= 'z';
```

Then it prints '{' characters in the mix. Any help? And another question is, how can I change this to work for all combos of upper and lower case too, is there a neat way of doing it?

Comment: There's a [cs50 stack exchange site](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/) if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

You print after you return from you recursion, but you should print when the recursion has reached the end (or beginning, in your case) of the string. In other words, printing should be an alternative branch to recursing:

```
void stringcycler(int n, int len, char *pass)
{
    if (n != 0) {
        for (pass[len - n] = 'a'; pass[len - n] <= 'z'; pass[len - n]++) {            
            stringcycler(n - 1, len, pass);
        }
    } else {
        printf("%s ", pass);
    }
}
```

The `if` part constructs the strings as it recurses further down. The `else` part does something with the constructed string. (Of course, you must include `'z'` in your loop. Your original code only prints the z in the last place, because it prints after ther recursion returns, which means thet the char buffer is in a condition that wouldn't (re-)enter the loop.)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a generic backtracking algorithm for generating the password. The idea here is to imagine filling the slots for a given char array `a`. We will be generating the possible candidates for the given position `k` for the array `a`. I have taken the candidates as lower case ascii letters `a-z` and upper case ASCII letters `A-Z`. If you want to include other ASCII characters, just modify the construct_candidates function accordingly.
Once the array is filled i.e. k becomes `PASS_LEN`, we know we have generated the password, we can process it however we like, I have just printed the password here.
The value of PASS_LEN macro can be adjusted to generate password of any desired length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PASS_LEN 2

static char* construct_candidates (char a[], int k, int *count)
{
    /* Lower case ASCII */
    int min1 = 97; 
    int max1 = 122; 

    /* Upper case ASCII */
    int min2 = 65; 
    int max2 = 90; 

    *count = (max1 - min1 + 1) + (max2 - min2 + 1); 
    char *cand = calloc(*count, sizeof(char));
    if (cand == NULL) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }   
    int idx = 0;
    for (int i = min1; i <= max1; i++) {
        cand[idx] = i;
        idx++;
    }   
    for (int i = min2; i <= max2; i++) {
        cand[idx] = i;
        idx++;
    }   

    return cand;
}

static void backtrack(char a[], int k)
{
    int i;
    if (k == PASS_LEN) {
        for (i = 0; i < PASS_LEN; i++) {
            printf("%c", a[i]);
        }   
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }   

    int cand_count = 0;
    char *cand = construct_candidates(a, k, &cand_count);
    if (cand == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to get candidates\n");
        return;
    }   
    for (i = 0; i < cand_count; i++) {
        a[k] = cand[i];
        backtrack(a, k + 1); 
    }
    free(cand);
}

int main()
{
    char a[PASS_LEN] = {'\0'};
    backtrack(a, 0); 
}
```